# In need for clarification of Aorai's frama-c YA language

Tags: frama-c

In the example provided by the official manual of Aorai plugin https://frama-c.com/download/frama-c-aorai-manual.pdf the example.ya file is the following

```
%accept: S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, S7;

S1 : { CALL(main)   } -> S2 
   ;
S2 : { opa().r>=0 } -> S3 
   ;
S3 : { opa().return<=5000 } -> S4
   ;
S4 : { !RETURN(opa) } -> S5
   ;
S5 : { RETURN(opb)  } -> S6
     ;
S6 : { RETURN(main) } -> S7
     ;
S7 :                  -> S7     
   ;
```

My question is why do we have to specify at the state S4 that `{!RETURN(opa)}` why don't we replace it by `{ CALL(opb) }`?

The main function corresponding to this automaton  is

```
int main() {
  if (rr<5000) rr=opa(rr);
  opb();
  goto L6;
  opc();
 L6:
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!RETURN(opa)` indicates that the current event must *not* be a `return` from the `opa` function. If you have a look at the whole automaton:

```
%init: S0;
%accept: S0, S1, S2,S3,S4,S5,S6;
S0 : { CALL(main) } -> S1;
;
S1 : { opa().r<5000 }
 -> S2
;
S2 : { opa().return<=5000 } -> S3
;
S3 : { !RETURN(opa) } -> S4
;
S4 : { RETURN(opb) } -> S5
;
S5 : { RETURN(main)} -> S6
;
S6 : -> S6
;
```

and taking into account that a transition must be crossed at each call or return event, we can see that in fact this event must be a call to `opb` (so that we can return from `opb` during the transition from `S4` to `S5`. In fact, if the code is correct with respect to the automaton, there is a call to `opa` when in state `S1` (with an argument less than `5000`), followed by a return from `opa` (with a result less than or equal to `5000`), bringing the program back into `main` (the very first transition from `S0` to `S1` is done at the start of the program).

**EDIT** following the update to the original question:
As should be clear from the description above, yes, the guard between `S3` and `S4` could have been written `{CALL(opb)}` without really changing the specification.